# Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate X bytes)

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal-6, flot

I saw this question, but the answer did not help me to solve the problem. So I'm sending a new question.

It drupal 6 site, that in this part it use the flot javascript to open files.
It's work when I open few files but when I increase it, I get a blank page and in the error_log I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 524288000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 107678417 bytes) in /path/to/site/includes/common.inc on line 167, referer: http://server/spectra/list
```

I tried to increase the size of memory_limit in php.ini & .htaccess, I saw that the size changed with phpinfo()
but when I load the page I get exactly the same error with the same number. I increase the size from 128M to 1024M and it still give the same error with the same number 524288000.
Where this  number is set?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems likely that you're buffering the entire contents of the files in memory some how. It'd be better to stream them if possible.   I know its not a direct answer to your question, which is why I'm adding a comment instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell you directly where to find the setting but I *can* tell you how.

If you're using a *nix system, do

```
grep -r memory_limit /path/to/drupal/installation
```

If you're on Windows, use a(n advanced) text editor to search in the path.

I suspect you'll find the setting in either index.php or settings.php.

Answer (score 0):

You right!

I had in drupal:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');
```

This is the reason why it was fix on 524288000 no matter what I wrote in php.ini.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you find the answer acceptable, please mark it as accepted. That will do as far as thanking me goes. :)